Acceder desde una app externa a wordpress Error al intentar comparar contraseña MD5
Resulta que estoy haciendo una aplicación web de una pagina que esta hecha en wordpress
La plataforma principal en la cual se registran los usuarios es wordpress, y se supone que desde la app pueden también ingresar y loguearse, pero me surgió el inconveniente, de que no puedo comparar la contraseña desde la app por que se supone que la contraseña que se crea desde wordpress, estaba en MD5, pero al revisar la tabla de wp_users el campo user_pass no contiene como tal un MD5, sino una criptografia diferente..
Para eso estoy accediendo desde php a la base de datos de wordpress y por medio de un formulario intento mandar las credenciales de acceso para consultar la información y comparar el usuario y contraseña.
Html
<form name="formlog" id="formlog" action="">
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="emailToLogin" class="form-label text-white">Email</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control input-primario" id="strEmail" name="strEmail" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="PasswordToLogin" class="form-label text-white">Contraseña</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control input-primario" id="strPassword" name="strPassword">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3 form-check">
              <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
              <label class="form-check-labe text-white" for="exampleCheck1">Recuerdame</label>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="bttn-small buttonc-gradient d-block mx-auto">INGRESAR</button>

Capturo la información y la envío al controlador por medio de XMLHttpRequest con JavaScript
const formlog = document.querySelector("#formlog");
formlog.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
e.preventDefault();

let strEmail = document.querySelector('#strEmail').value;
let strPassword = document.querySelector('#strPassword').value;
console.log(strEmail+strPassword);

    if (strEmail == "" || strPassword == "" ) {
            Swal.fire({
              icon: 'error',
              title: 'Atención',
              text: 'Ingresa el usuario y la contraseña'
              
            });
            return false;
    }else{
        var request = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXobjet('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
        var ajaxUrl = base_url+'home/loginUser';
        var formData = new FormData(formlog);
        request.open("POST",ajaxUrl,true);
        request.send(formData);
        //console.log('se puede iniciar el login');
    }
   });

En el controlador verifico los datos para enviarlos al modelo encriptando con md5 la contraseña como se suponia funcionaba la de wordpress
public function loginUser(){
        //dep($_POST);
        if($_POST) {
            if (empty($_POST['strEmail']) || empty($_POST['strPassword']) ) {
                $arrResponse = array('status' => false, 'msg' => 'Error de datos, Campos Vacios');
            }else{
                 $strUsuario = strtolower(strClean($_POST['strEmail']));
                 $passwordEncrypt = $_POST['strPassword']; 
                 $strPassword = MD5($passwordEncrypt);
                 $requestUser = $this->model->logUser($strUsuario, $strPassword);
                 }
        }
    }

y en el modelo hacia la consulta directa a las bases de datos de wordpress a la tabla wp-users para comparar la informacion del formulario, si existía una conisidencia pues ya crear la session
public function logUser(string $user, string $pass)
    {
        $this->strUsuario = $user;
        $this->strPass = $pass;
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_users WHERE 
                user_email = '$this->strUsuario' and 
                user_pass = '$this->strPass' ";
        $request = $this->select($sql);
        return $request;
    }

Pero me retornaba consultas vacias, y al comparar el encryptado que me genera php al que se genera en la tabla wp_users en wordpress en el campo contraseña eran totalmente diferentes
Hasta donde tengo entendido, uno puede crear los usuarios desde Mysql, usando la función MD5, lo que genera un valor (como este 4fc71da499f4... ) en ese campo user_pass, pero después que el usuario se loguea en wordpress, el valor de ese campo cambia a uno como este $P$BZryzhmZgg....
Hay alguna forma de saber como se genera esa contraseña o como puedo hacer una comparación de esa contraseña con los datos de ingreso desde la APP?
O si debo usar la api rest alguien me puede dar una pequeña mano para guiarme?

Si, el cifrado cambio hace mucho, si quieres crear usuarios de forma externa mejor usa la API de wordpress o crea tu propia API, puedes conectarse a wp_create_user() para cifrar los datos de forma correcta, aunque tambien puedes buscar la wp_check_password() función para ver como funciona.

Gracias Jefferzon por responder, me podrías guiar un poco porfavor?

Como ingresas a los datos, lo haces mediante la API, es una app movil o es una app web aparte?

Por favor actualiza tu pregunta agregando el metodo que usas para verificar la contraseña, te recomiendo leer [ask] y como hacer un [example] con más información puedo guiarte de mejor forma.

editada @JefferzonBol muchas gracias por lo que me puedas ayudar a aclarar el panorama!

voy a darte un ejemplo asumiendo que la nueva APP esta dentro del mismo servidor donde esta la APP de WP, lo que significa que tienes acceso al código fuente de WordPress.
Para empezar WP ya tiene funciones para esto, puedes usar wp_authenticate() que autentica a un usuario, este recibe dos parámetros, el Email y la contraseña en texto plano.
La otra opción es usar la función wp_check_password() que sirve solo para verificar la contraseña del usuario, esta función recibe 3 parámetros, La contraseña en texto plano, La contraseña hasheada, es decir, la que ya almaceno Wordpress y el Id del usuario cuya contraseña quieres verificar.
Ahora, asumiendo que la nueva APP esta dentro del mismo servidor entonces deberías de poder llamar al archivo wp-load.php, si llamas a ese archivo puedes usar las funciones de WordPress como si estuvieses dentro del entorno, por ejemplo:
Usando la función `wp_authenticate()`:

`function autenticar_usuario(){

    define('WP_USE_THEMES', false); // Esto permite cargar el core sin cargar los temas, lo cual mejora la carga
    require_once('/ruta/a/tu/wordpress/wp-load.php'); // Agrega la ruta correcta

    $email = 'user@user.com';
    $password = 'Mi Contraseña';

    $user = wp_authenticate( $email, $password );

    // Si falla retornamos false o puedes retornar un mensaje de error
    if ( is_wp_error( $user ) ) :
        return $user->get_error_message();
    endif;

    // Si todo es correcto puedes retornar true
    return true;

}

Aquí wp_authenticate() verifica por si misma la contraseña del usuario identificándolo por su email, cargamos wp-load.php para poder usar el Core y ponemos WP_USE_THEMES en false para evitar cargar los temas.
function autenticar_usuario(){

    define('WP_USE_THEMES', false); // Esto permite cargar el core sin cargar los temas, lo cual mejora la carga
    require_once('/ruta/a/tu/wordpress/wp-load.php'); // Agrega la ruta correcta

    // Contraseña a verificar y hash almacenado en la base de datos
    $password = 'Mi Contraseña';
    $hash = '$P$B5G9E/sfJSA4bPBd.HpcDS0An7oGnN/'; // Hash de ejemplo

    // Si falla la verificación puedes retornar false
    // Opcional puedes pasar el user_id para que la consulta sea más rápida
    if ( !wp_check_password( $password, $hash ) ) :
        return false;
    endif;

    // Si todo es correcto puedes retornar true
    return true;

}

Esto solo verifica la contraseña, le pasas la contraseña en texto plano y el password ya hasheado, si hay coincidencia retornara true.
No lo he probado así que no estoy 100% seguro que funcione, pero te da una idea de poder donde empezar.

wow perfecto bro gracias ya mismo inicio!

Cool, si te funciona agradecería un voto positivo y que aceptes la respuestas.

Bro muchas gracias, realmente esta era la solución es super facil de implementar tal cual llamando a la función como lo describiste en tu respesta muchas gracias un crack!
